# Change Title's content on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem. I want to change my page title when I click on 1 of 5 tabs that I have on my page. The title of that page should change based on what tab was clicked. If would go something like this:

```
<div id="tab1"></div>
<div id="tab2"></div>
<div id="tab3"></div>
<div id="tab4"></div>
<div id="tab5"></div>
```

When clicked on tab1, title should change to "tab1, when clicked on tab2, title should change to tab2 and so on...

I tried with this jquery, but it didn't work. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    ('#tab2').click(function ()}{
        (document).title ('tab2');
    })
});
```

Can you please help me with that?

Thank you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="change-title" id="tab1">1</div>
<div class="change-title" id="tab2">2</div>
<div class="change-title" id="tab3">3</div>
<div class="change-title" id="tab4">4</div>
<div class="change-title" id="tab5">5</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change-title').on('click',function(){
         document.title = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Pure Js I can give you short version also

```js
function changeTitle(pagetitle){
document.title = pagetitle;
}
document.getElementById('tab1').onclick = function(){changeTitle("tab1")};
document.getElementById('tab2').onclick = function(){changeTitle("tab2")};
document.getElementById('tab3').onclick = function(){changeTitle("tab3")};
document.getElementById('tab4').onclick = function(){changeTitle("tab4")};
document.getElementById('tab5').onclick = function(){changeTitle("tab5")};
```

```html
<div id="tab1">A</div>
<div id="tab2">B</div>
<div id="tab3">C</div>
<div id="tab4">D</div>
<div id="tab5">E</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution could also be if you would make use of the [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method in jQuery. Then you could simply define your preferred title for each tab that should be displayed in the title tag and it's not bounded anymore to the name of your id.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab1" data-title="Tab 1"></div>
<div id="tab2" data-title="Tab 2"></div>
<div id="tab3" data-title="Tab 3"></div>
<div id="tab4" data-title="Tab 4"></div>
<div id="tab5" data-title="Tab 5"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div").click(function(){
  document.title = $(this).data("title");
});
```

Comment: You can't assume that the querent has only these mentioned divs in his page with data-title='something'

Comment: @Dherya No of course not, but OP could easily change the code to his needs? Wherever OP wants a title OP just has to add a `data-title` with the desired title to the specific div and jQuery will automatically grab the content  of it on click and set it as document title.

Comment: Yeah and +1 for your different approach :)  @Sven

Comment: @Dherya Thank you :)